# convergence of $e^{it\Delta}f$

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, harmonic-analysis, sobolev-spaces

I heard of a conjecture that

$e^{it\Delta}f\rightarrow f$ a.e. as $t\rightarrow 0$ for $f\in H^{1/4+\epsilon}$

but couldn't find a proper reference.

Comment: This paper of Vega should be helpful: http://www.jstor.org/stable/2047326.

Comment: Read for instance http://arxiv.org/pdf/1201.3342v1.pdf

Comment: See http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/882/how-to-write-a-good-mathoverflow-question?cb=1